# Query AWS or OU in master account with CDK from another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Busy building a AWS CDK stack on cdk-pipelines, and during one of my stages in the pipeline, I want to query the OU in the AWS Org to get a list of accounts ID's to run certain actions against in the stage.

Looking at the AwsCustomResource construct, something like this

```
     const OrgARN = 'arn:aws:organizations::123fake321:organization/o-onetwoabc'
     const awsCustom1 = new cr.AwsCustomResource(this, 'OUAccounts', {
       onUpdate: {
         service: 'Organizations',
         action: 'describeOrganization',
         physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of('VerificationToken')
       },
    policy: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({resources: [OrgARN]})
     });
```

But it does not work for me, when I do a `cdk deploy` I get the following :

```
Failed to create resource. Inaccessible host: `organizations.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `eu-central-1' region.
```

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

[AWS Organization](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/) is a global service.

[DescribeOrganizationalUnit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeOrganizationalUnit.html)

> This operation can be called only from the organization's management account or by a member account that is a delegated administrator for an AWS service.

[ListAccounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/APIReference/API_ListAccounts.html)

> This operation can be called only from the organization's management account or by a member account that is a delegated administrator for an AWS service.